# Add progressbar inside Ext.window

Tags: javascript, extjs

Could anyone help me insert below progress bar inside Ext.window?  or any other suggestions to add a progress bar inside Ext.window?

```
   var p = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
                    renderTo: Ext.body(),
                    width: 300
                });
                p.wait({
                    interval: 500, //bar will move fast!
                    duration: 50000,
                    increment: 100,
                    text: 'Updating',
                    scope: this,
                    fn: function () {
                        p.updateText('Done!');
                    }
                });
```

I want to insert progress bar in below window

```
var window = new Ext.Window({
            title: "export",
            height: 100,
            layout: 'fit',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    listeners: {
                        click: function () {
                            window.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            items: [{
                xtype: 'download',

                autoEl: {
                        tag: 'iframe',
                        src: 'www.google.com'

                    }
                }]
        }).show();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add progress bar to opened window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179996/how-to-add-progress-bar-to-opened-window)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do that. You could add the existing progress bar to the existing window:

```
window.add(p);
```

Or add the existing progress bar when creating the window:

```
new Ext.Window({
    items: [p]
);
```

Or create a new progress bar when creating the window:

```
new Ext.Window({
    items: [{
        xtype: 'progressbar'
    }]
);
```